# In datatables python, what is the equivalent to DT[grepl("Ap",V2)] used in R Data.Table?

Tags: python-3.x, datatables

I want to select all rows that have a value of Ap in column V2?  I want to do this where V2 might have (Apples, Carrots, Bananas) and the result will give me (Apples).
Said another way....I want to filter for items that have an Ap within column V2. What is the equivalent in the datatables python package?  Thanks.